# Sudden issue sending emails via relay: 454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure

Tags: email-relay

Since 2 days I experience a strange and unexpected issue with sending emails through a mail relay. The setup has been running without similar issues for over a year now.

Via Domain Filters only some emails are sent through the relay, some are sent through another relay (no new issues there) and some are sent directly. The log file for all emails sent through the troublesome relay shows "454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure" as an error. When searching for this specific error message, only information regarding Exchange can be found.

But the relay is an exim server running on a Sophos UTM 9, so this system should not produce Exchange-messages. There is no Exchange-server involved from our side at all.

According to all logs and configuration change audits, nothing changed in the configuration of either the Salesforce org or the UTM server. The only thing different is that now emails from Salesforce come in through mx2-cdg-sp3.mta.salesforce.com,
mx4-cdg-sp3.mta.salesforce.com and mx1-cdg-sp3.mta.salesforce.com (before it was smtp02-cdg-sp3.mta.salesforce.com).

That change should not cause the issues. I have verified that the credentials and port work correctly - a thunderbird configured to send through the relay with the same credentials works fine. And yes, the emails are actually sent through the relay.

Setting up another SF org to use the relay results in the same error messages.

Has anyone encountered such a behaviour / this error message - without an Exchange server involved?
Any ideas what I could try additionally?

Comment: Is SF authenticating to your relay? If so, then relay logs should clearly say why incoming connection is failing auth and which party (SF or relay) is guilty. If there's no auth to relay, then it's unclear what's going on, you should open a support case with SF.

Comment: 454 is a SMTP error code, it's not Exchange-specific but the support engineer tackling your case might not know this. They do have a point - if you're doing auth and auth fails at relay, it's likely (but not guaranteed) to be a relay-side issue or an issue with your credentials.  Escalate to your account executive or (if you have higher tiers of support plan) escalate the case to next-level support.

Comment: Hardly. If we stand up a SMTP relay with control over protocol messages, we can output whatever message we want. Is it possible that exim fronting Sophos sends this response? It's possible. Since you (hopefully) have access to exim logs, _you can verify this_.